# How to validate if the file not passed in

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have script that takes file from user with option -y or -n and -d is required
script runs ./example.sh -d file -y or -n
variable

`file=""`

I need to do validation on if the user did not pass file in for example

```
./example.sh -y       --- it should give error "must provide file"`
./example.sh -n       --- it should give error "must provide file"`
./example.sh -d       --- it should give error "must provide file"
./example.sh -y -n       --- it should give error "must provide file"
```

i came up with this but its not working
#checking if the file is provided

```
if [ $file -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "No file provided"
    exit 1
fi
```

```
# Does the file exist 
which works for checking if the file exists but it only check if the file in there

  if [[ ! -f $file ]]; then
      echo
      echo "Error: The file $file does not exist."
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: Why not just loop over the arguments with a `case` statement and for the `-d` case, check the next argument with `[ -s "$next" ]` (to test the filename exists on the system and is non-empty) You can handle them all that way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin whats -s stands for and to check the file exists i already have the code

Comment: `-s` checks if file exists and is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply loop over the arguments and test the `-d`, `-n` and `-y` options in a `case` statement. The filename must follow the `-d` option as I understand it. When the `-d` option is processed in your `case` statement check that the next argument holds a filename that exists on the system and is non-empty, if so, set the filename, e.g. `filename="${argv[i+1]}"`.

When you exit the option processing loop, simply test if `filename` is set and you have your answer.

A short example could be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

argc=$#         ## argument count
argv=("$@")     ## array holding arguments (argument vector)

filename=       ## filename is empty

## loop over all arguments, filename must follow -d 
for ((i = 0; i < argc; i++)); do
  case "${argv[i]}" in
        ## file exists and non-empty, set filename to argument
    -d ) [ -s "${argv[i+1]}" ] && { filename="${argv[i+1]}"; };;
    -n ) # do whatever for option n
        ;;
    -y ) # do whatever for option y
        ;;
  esac
done

[ -n "$filename" ] || {   ## check filename set or exit
  printf "error: file empty or not readable.\n" >&2
  exit 1
}

## valid filename received
printf "file '%s' found - script running.\n" "$filename"
```

Only if a valid filename is given after the `-d` option will the script run. Otherwise it will give an error message and exit.

**Examples**

```
$ ./process-opts.sh -y -n
error: file empty or not readable.
```

or

```
$ ./process-opts.sh -y -d -n
error: file empty or not readable.
```

Finally

```
$ ./process-opts.sh -y -d README -n
file 'README' found - script running.
```

or in any order:

```
$ ./process-opts.sh -y -n -d README
file 'README' found - script running.
```